# Restricted SFTP-only access to a single directory using OpenSSH

Tags: ssh, sftp, restrictions

I configured **SFTP** using open SSH by using following link on my **Windows Server 2012**

[Installing SFTP (SSH FTP) Server on Windows Server 2012 R2](http://woshub.com/installing-sftp-ssh-ftp-server-on-windows-server-2012-r2/)

It is well configured and perfectly working fine.

I have one user and I shared it with my client so they can connect to my server using SFTP connection port 22, and they are connecting well.

The problem is that they are accessing and can see my whole files and folder server I just want to give the access of only one folder to them.

Is it possible? If yes than How?

I want that if they connect to my server than they can only see that specific folder I allow them to see and access.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to install the CygSSH package:

https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/CygSSH

The documentation describes how to configure sftp-only access.